# An NPM package extends an interface in the global scope. How to override this type definition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql-mesh

I use the [graphql-mesh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-mesh) package in my project. This library has [the following type definition](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-mesh/blob/e7a8e47d564e45ec60204dbca6f1f870671506e9/packages/config/src/index.ts#L27-L31):

```
declare global {
  interface ObjectConstructor {
    keys<T>(obj: T): Array<keyof T>;
  }
}
```

This type definition breaks my build. I have errors like that:

```
Argument of type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

278       expect(bar.get(Object.keys(given.foo)[0]))
```

How can I fix it? Is there an option to override this type in my project? Or can TypeScript compiler ignore this type definition?

Comment: I'd be inclined to fork the project, remove that extension, and do a PR. [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) has been standard for years now, and it returns `Array<string>` (`string[]`), not `Array<keyof T>`.

Comment: If you're looking to use the project [graphql-mesh](https://graphql-mesh.com/) then you have the wrong npm package. The proper ones are much more actively maintained. See the installation instructions: https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-mesh